# Normality of AR(1) Model

Tags: time-series, normality-assumption, autoregressive

I'm stuck trying to understand the relationship between normality and autoregressive models. If we have a variable Y(t) given by an AR(1) model with zero mean for the marginal distribution, how do we actually check for normality for the conditional and marginal distributions given that the Y(t) is stationary? Some questions seems to relate the normality of the error term as a criteria, but I'm not sure how to interpret that.

Answer (score 1):

An AR(1) model for a zero-mean $y_t$ is
$$
y_t = \varphi_1 y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t
$$
where $\varepsilon_t$ are i.i.d. We can also express $y_t$ recursively as
$$
y_t = y_0 + \varepsilon_t+\varphi_1\varepsilon_{t-1}+\varphi_1^2\varepsilon_{t-2}+\dots+\varphi_1^{t-1}\varepsilon_{t-1}.
$$
If we take $y_0$ as given, then $y_t$ is a constant plus a weighted sum of i.i.d. random variables. If we also assume $\varepsilon_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ in addition to being i.i.d., then $y_t$ is a constant plus a weighted sum of independent normal random variables and thus also normal.
If $\varepsilon_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and we do not take $y_0$ as given, it is sufficient to require $y_0\sim N(0,\sigma_0^2)$ and independent of the $\varepsilon$s. Then $y_t$ is a weighted sum of independent normal random variables and thus also normal.

If you are interested in assumptions, they are usually made on the error term, not the dependent variable, so you would check whether the $\varepsilon$s are normal. If they are, and you are willing to condition on $y_0$ or assume it to be normal and independent of the $\varepsilon$s, then $y_t$ is also normal.
If you do not assume $\varepsilon$s to be i.i.d. and only say they are all zero mean, then it would be impossible to test any distributional assumptions empirically, as you would only have a single realization from each distribution. The same holds for $y_0$ as it is a single realization of the underlying random variable.

Comment: Thanks Prof! This would be true for both conditional and unconditional distributions?

Comment: @user35032, well, yes, because depending on what information you condition upon (info available at time $t-1$, $t-2$ or whatever other), $y_t$ will be a constant plus a weighted sum of random normal variables.

Comment: Regarding the unconditional distribution, let me update my answer (in a few minutes).